# Summarize similar subscriptions via loop through array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am applying filters on each column of a over 20-column material-table. The subscriptions on each filter look like this:

```
id_Filter = new FormControl();

filteredValues = {
    id: ''
};

this.id_Filter.valueChanges.subscribe((id_FilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['id'] = id_FilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });
```

Is it possible to summarize those similar subscriptions in a forEach-loop by a string-array, like this:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'id',
    'description',
    'weight',
    ...
]

id_Filter = new FormControl();
description_Filter = new FormControl();
weight_Filter = new FormControl();

filteredValues = {
    id: '', description: '', weight: ''
};

this.displayedColumns.forEach(element => {
      let _filter = element + '_Filter';
      let _value = element + '_FilterValue';
      this[_filter].valueChanges.subscribe((_value: string) => {
        this.filteredValues[element] = _value;
        this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
      })
    });
```

Thx